# write batch file to copy a text file from windows system to unix system

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy the result of the bleow script to a describe location of a unix system.
the script is

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=0
set FILEPATH=C:\VPM-WNC-MANUAL-MIGRATION
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,5,6 delims= " %%a in (`findstr /c:"Cod " %FILEPATH%\INPUT\INPUT.txt`) do (        
set x=%%b
set x=!x:~3!
set y=%%c        
if %%c LSS 10 set y=!y:~1!
set item!Counter!=%%a-!x!#!y!        
set /a Counter+=1
)
set result=%item0%
for /l %%i in (0,1,!Counter!) do echo !item%%i!>> %FILEPATH%\OUTPUT\result.txt  
echo \n
move %FILEPATH%\INPUT\INPUT.txt %FILEPATH%\DONE\
echo  >> %FILEPATH%\INPUT\INPUT.txt
move %FILEPATH%\OUTPUT\result.txt %FILEPATH%\RESULT\
echo  >> %FILEPATH%\OUTPUT\result.txt   
endlocal
```

the result.txt shoul go to unix folder

Answer (score 3):

[PuTTy scp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe) may be an option for you.  Works like secure copy on linux.

e.g.

pscp result.txt your_username@remotehost:/some/remote/directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use Samba to mount a unix filesystem as a Windows drive. Then copy the file normally, as if it were to a local hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ftp or scp to upload the result to a unix server assuming you have accesses to those services.